# Issue reading Bold fonts with Tesseract API / Tess4j

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, jna, tess4j

I am having problem in reading BOLD font characters from image with Tesseract API http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/.

Is Tesseract having issues with BOLD fonts. How to read BOLD fonts with Tesseract / tess4j?

Do I need to add some libs with Tesseract to read bold characters?

Comment: I am open with using any technology. Can anyone suggest me any open source OCR library (regardless of technology).

Comment: I think Tesseract is best open source library you can get. If your target image contain only bold character then set property of tesseract "tessedit_char_whitelist" and put only bold character as its value.